# Formatting Scala code in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have Scala code like this:

```
def myMethod(myInt: Int, myFloat: Float, myString: String): Unit = {
     //method body
}
```

I want to format it exactly like this:

```
 def myMethod(
     myInt: Int,
     myFloat: Float, 
     myString: String): Unit = {
     //method body
    }
```

So the caveat is that each parameter has to be in it's own line and needs to indented by 4 spaces. I have tried the Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java, under the "Wrapping and Braces" tab, and selected the "Wrap always" option for "Method declaration parameters". But that doesn't indent the code correctly. Anyway to do this?

Comment: Appart from actual Intellij-specific answer, you might also be interested in the [scalafmt project](https://olafurpg.github.io/scalafmt/). It's an IDE-independent formatter, but the project does include an Intellij plugin (as well as a command line tool, an SBT plugin...). There is a setting `continuationIndent.defnSite`, which does what you want (the default is 4 spaces). Note that scalafmt is especially nice if you want to use one of the included preset styles (with maybe a couple tweaks here and there) rather than set every single option yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should set for **Scala** but not Java: Settings > Editor > Code Style > Scala, Wrapping and Braces > Method declaration parameters. Select the "Wrap always".

It works for me.
[image]